# Change Push Notifications Content Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, ios11

As we know this function called when the Push notification banner is ready to be presented.

```
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter* )center 
willPresentNotification:(UNNotification* )notification 
withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions
 options))completionHandler{


 }
```

In this function there is notification of Class (UNNotification) which contains the info that are going to be presented on banner.
Now question is that can we change the content of Push notification within the application?
I can store all the content in this way.

```
NSString *title=notification.request.content.title;
NSString *subTitle=notification.request.content.subTitle;
```

and so on.
But the issue is that those properties(title, subTite) are just readonly.
Is there a way to change the content within this completion handler or in some other method?

Comment: why you are not change the payload of your push notification from the backend. aps will show in banner but you can add more information in payload dictionary

Comment: yes, it a solution but i don't have access of backend right now. for some reasons i need to do this within the application.

Answer (score 4):

Create [NotificationService](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension) extension. When you send mutable-content flag as 1 inside aps in payload, iOS system launches your extension and gives you a chance to change the notification content. This will work even when your app is in killed state. Only downside is that this is available only on iOS 10 and above.

Comment: Fallback for older iOS version would be to schedule then a local push notification - this behavior worked fine for us :)

Comment: @Lepidopteron: I guess by scheduling local notification, you mean sending a silent push and then scheduling the local notification. But, in that case, silet push won't get delivered if user has terminated the app.

Comment: Its a good soultion indeed but i don't have acces to backend right now. Means there is no one who can update the New P12 file (Extension file) from backend right now.

Comment: @ZaheerUdeenBabar: Then I am afraid, there is nothing much you can do. Notification System is going to show the payload as recieved.